# How to know if a point-to-point network is synchronous?

Tags: networking, synchronization, broadcast, distributed-system

I am implementing a local-time delta-timeless reliable broadcast. using a point-to-point network with TCP connection between every two processes.

The requirement for such broadcast protocol is for the point-to-point network to be synchronous:

From the slides in school:

- A point-to-point network is synchronous if:

  - There is a know upper bound to execute a step
  - Local clocks has known bounded rate of drift
    with respect to real time
  - There is a known upper bound on message
    delay ( consists of the time to send, transport and receive)

But how do I find these upper bound? i.e. is the message delay the maximum latency between any two processes? How do I know if the latency is bounded?

Comment: On a point-to-point link, broadcast is a moot concept since there is only one possible receiver for the broadcast.

Comment: What I mean is I connect every processes in a network with point to point.

Comment: And that is really the opposite of broadcast. Broadcast sends to every host, while point-to-point sends to a single host.

Comment: I have something like a for loop to send to every processes in turn.

Comment: There are almost no synchronous networks in use. Two processes running on the same computer communicate over an asynchronous network. Neither Windows, Linux or Mac uses a scheduler with real-time guarantees, so your processes could in theory be halted forever.